# How to Draw a northern hemisphere map using Matplotlib basemap and the Projection is orthographic projection

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, orthographic

I want to draw a map,how to set the display region only is northern hemisphere,the picture which I want like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdc9i.jpg)
thanks in advance!

```
map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=0,ax=axes1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer myself

```
map1 = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=0, resolution=None)
```

map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=0,llcrnrx=-6370997., llcrnry=0., urcrnrx=map1.urcrnrx/2., urcrnry=map1.urcrnry/2.,ax=axes1)